# Rermove Pod raises Error: dyld: Library not loaded:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods, xcode7

I use Cocoapods in my Xcode project and I installed SwiftyJSON as a pod:

```
target 'TestProject' do 
   pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.0' 
end
```

After a while I removed it from the pod and did: `pod install` to perform the delete.

When I run my project on the simulator I have no problem but when I run I on a device the app crashes with the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/87774D56-6869-40B8-87BC-373C160CCE95/TestProject.app/TestProject
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of CocoaPods on Xcode 7. see this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3661) on Github.